# Hibernate not showing the performance log

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, log4j, logback

I am trying to get performance statistics from Hibernate. I've already enabled hibernate statistics in the spring context.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.some.package" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

However I am getting a empty collect from the debug log.

23:01:52.075 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.stat.Statistics - **HQL: {}, time: {}ms, rows: {}**

I am using hibernate version 3.6.

Comment: *I am not getting a empty collect from the debug log*: I'm confused. What are you expecting to happen, and what happens instead? On a side nte, why are you using a completelly obsolete, unmaintained version of Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

Turn out this is a logger issue

Did some debugging, I see both hql, time, rows contain correct information. But the logger still not printing out the correct format. We are using logback 1.0.12, I wonder if this will cause a problem?

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "UnnecessaryBoxing" })
public void queryExecuted(String hql, int rows, long time) {
    if (isDebugEnabled) {
        PERF_LOG.debug( "HQL: {}, time: {}ms, rows: {}", new Object[] {hql, Long.valueOf( time ), Long.valueOf(rows)} );
    }
    queryExecutionCount.getAndIncrement();
```